# 54 V input on one, or two 40 V linear regulators? (LM317)

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, linear-regulator, step-down

Before I explain the situation I am in, please bear in mind that I am completely new to electronics, and I want to spend as little money as possible on my current project because of outrageous pricing. For context, a single 60 V step down converter or anything similar will cost about 25 dollars in my country (Sweden). Also, I am a student trying to make do with what I have.

So here is my problem: I have 5 LM317 linear regulators on hand at the moment. I see that they are only rated for a 40 V maximum input voltage, which obviously isn't capable of the 52 V input in my E-scooter (Kugoo G-Booster). Wiring them in parallel will not affect the voltage, to my knowledge. And wiring them in series won't be possible because the first regulator will take on the complete 52 volts. How do I go about using them? Any suggestions as to a working solution? For some background info, they will power a turn-signal and RGB system as well as a wireless relay. That's about it. The power is being taken from the motor controller, which outputs 54 V when fully charged and about 37 V when depleted. Thanks for any and all info!

I have mostly read on about the topic, but I cannot find any similar problems from my research. I hope to get 12 V output at a relatively high amperage.

Comment: "relatively high amperage" is concerning here. Unless you actually go for a switching regulator or equivalent, you're going to have to dissipate 40 watts for every amp of current, which is far more than your regulator or typical resistors/transistors would be able to safely dissipate. Specialty linear devices and heatsinks for that much power will cost you more than $25 in total.

Comment: Even if you can find one with an adequate input voltage, a linear amplifier is a *very* bad idea for this application. You'll be wasting a ton of power, and dealing with the heat dissipation is going to be very difficult.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please can you edit your question and add the required typical current and peak current drawn. Without that, the question cannot be answered. Thanks.

Comment: You can use something like this ... but devices should hard to find ... https://manycircuits.blogspot.com/2017/05/dc-step-down-circuit-12v-24v-36v-48v.html https://www.thierry-lequeu.fr/data/TOPSWITCH/AN32.pdf

Comment: No, that won’t work. You need a switch mode converter with at least 60 V rating, preferably 80+ V. No other solution would be as cheap as 25 USD. Send me your number and I’ll swish you a contribution towards it.

Comment: You could get a converter from china for much less. My experience for the most part has been good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say a switching regulator is too expensive... but I'm afraid a linear regulator would be even more expensive. You don't specify a current load, but you do say "relatively high amperage". Stepping 52 V down to 12 V means you'll have 40 V across the regulator, and that 40 V, multiplied by the current, is the amount of power you're wasting in the regulator. For 1 A output, your regulator will have to dissipate 40 W. That's a *lot* of power; these things are typically rated for about 2~5 W, and that's with a good heatsink. So you'd need to share the power between ten or twenty of them, and each one would need a good heatsink (expensive) and active cooling. You're probably looking at a total cost of well over $100, and that's assuming you get it right on the first try.

Switching regulators are really the only sensible option for an application like this. They don't have the drawback linear regulators do; the input current doesn't have to equal the output current, so they can be much more efficient. A good buck converter could get you 95% or better efficiency, and possibly even work without any heatsink at all other than the PCB it's mounted to. I'd shell out the 25 bucks if I were you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. As stated I am completely new to all of this, and had no idea Linear regulators wouldn’t work. I will consider all the things stated and take a look into a switching regulator. Thanks again!